# How to blend in gnome-panel?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm not a big fan of Unity, although I'm not a big fan of downgrading either.. So I've installed gnome-panel to try to get a better feel for Gnome 2. I quickly noticed that it is horrendous.

1) Applications/Places are gray, not white.
2) The bottom part of the panel where the open windows / taskbar is are white.

I love the Ambiance theme so I would prefer not to get an answer involving switching themes.

I saw another question that involved editing a css file in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css but it didn't have any change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, that's a screenshot of what it looks like. I get the same desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the full gnome package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome
```

Reboot, and login with gnome-classic. If that doesn't do it, try creating a new user or loging in on the guest account to see if the problem is limited to your account.

Comment: Unfortunately the guest account did the same, and installing the gnome package didn't do it either ://

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? Maybe I don't understand your problem. (I noticed your comment about the screenshot, but I'm not sure which one you meant)

Comment: This is the screenshot I was referring too :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZSMr.png

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is just the way the theme is made. You would have to make a new one to change that.

Comment: Aww. I don't know why they would make it that way, although I don't think they would purposely make it like that. Must be some rendering issue or something :/